# org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: ERROR: cannot set an index-time boost, unindexed or norms are omitted for field

Tags: solr, solrj

I am actually facing the error while indexing using solr as follows:

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: ERROR: [doc=Ask_67] cannot set an index-time boost, unindexed or norms are omitted for field commitAs: index
```

The field "commitAs" on which the error is pointing is not used for indexing.

I have already set this field in schema.xml

< field name="commitAs" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="false" omitNorms = "true" />

any help appreciated.

Comment: <field name="commitAs" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="false" omitNorms = "true"/>

Comment: Do you really want this field in your schema? As I see you are not indexing it and storing it?

Comment: try with making it as indexed=true.

Comment: i dont want it in schema as it is used only to specify whether the document is new one or updated one. but if i dont specify commitAs field in schema.xml, it gives error as unknown field and non ok server error 500. i dont need this field for indexing.

Comment: it would be better if you share the schema.xml..

Comment: Did you define them under the fields tag?

Comment: Before Solr 4.8, fields had to be enclosed in the fields tag and the types in the types tag...so wanted to confirm the same. which version are you using/

Comment: <field name="commitAs" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms = "true"/>
<field name="author" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="desc" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="pages" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

these are the fields in my schema.xml and i dont want to store and index commitAs,when i set indexed="false" & stored="false" it shows the above mentioned error. when i set this to true it indexed and stored commitAs also

Comment: my problem got solved when i set indexed and stored value as true but it also stores the commitAs field and indexed it which i dont want

Comment: if you dont want the field to be part of the document, remove it from the schema.xml. When you mention the field there, it will be the part of the document... isnt it?

Comment: yes previously it wasn't there but at that time it throws the error, unknown field commitAs.

Comment: You must have have mentioned it in your schema...may be for the uniqueKey or for the defaultSearch...

Comment: so what to do if i have to remove these two error(unknown field and unindexed) and dont want to index this field also??

Comment: for the unknown field issue: the issue is because the field in not mentioned in document and used somewhere in the schema...

Comment: ohk.. thanku for your help..

Comment: As this question was never "answered" (in StackOverflow terms), one might recommend closing it.  Alternatively, if PriyankaBansal or @AbhijitBashetti can supply an answer, the OP can accept it.

Comment: I don't know if the issue is been resolved for @PriyankaBansal...